# F# AsyncWaitOne and AsyncReadToEnd

Tags: f#, asynchronous

I am working ti old F# code from *Expert F#*.  However, the example doesn't build anymore.
The following two calls don't seem to exist:

```
semaphore.AsyncWaitOne(?millisecondsTimeout=timeout)
```

and

```
reader.ReadToEndAsync()
```

Does anyone know what these have been replaced with or if I am just missing a reference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's now called [`Async.AwaitWaitHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370283.aspx).

`AsyncReadToEnd` is in the F# [PowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: `AsyncReadToEnd` extension method has disappeared from latest PowerPack releases. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23293624/1480391

Answer (score 2):

By now, FSharp PowerPack project has been broken up into smaller modules for any further development.
Specifically, the AsyncStreamReader class and the extension methods for the reading from a StreamReader, WebClient, etc. the new project is [FSharpx.Async](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Async/).

Comment: That project hasn't been updated for a while now (Feb 2018).  Has it been superseded by something else?

Answer (score 0):

1) AsyncWaitOne is now called [`Async.AwaitWaitHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370283.aspx).

2) `AsyncReadToEnd()` extension method does not exists anymore in the [FSharp.PowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/).
It has been replaced with the **`AsyncStreamReader`** dedicated type that contains proper asynchronous implementation of stream reading (like `ReadToEnd`, `ReadLine`, etc.)

It can be used like that:

```
async { 
  use asyncReader = new AsyncStreamReader(stream)
  return! asyncReader.ReadToEnd() }
```

Note: Once you have installed [FSharp.PowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/), the `AsyncStreamReader` type will be 'injected' in the `Microsoft.FSharp.Control` namespace