# The field, constructor or member 'AsyncReadToEnd' is not defined error

Tags: f#, system.reactive

I am learning RX (Reactive Extensions), and have found someone posted some code nearly one year ago using F# and RX to make a simple webCrawler.  I tried to see if I can re-use the code.  I download RX, and create a F# windows application, add reference to System.Reactive. My IDE is VS 2010 Ultimate, RX version is: 1.1.11111.  The following is the code:

```
#light
open System
open System.Linq
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Net
open System.IO
open System.Threading
open System.Text.RegularExpressions
open System.Reactive
open System.Reactive.Linq

let create f =
    Observable.Create<_>(fun x ->
        f x
        new System.Action((fun () -> ())))

let ofAsync async =
    create (fun obs -> Async.StartWithContinuations(async, obs.OnNext,obs.OnError,obs.OnError))

let fromEvent (event:IEvent<_,_>) = create (fun x -> event.Add x.OnNext)

let tickEvent = new Event<unit> ()
let tickEventObs = tickEvent.Publish |> fromEvent

let fetch(url:string) =
    async { let req = WebRequest.Create(url)
            let! resp = req.AsyncGetResponse()
            let stream = resp.GetResponseStream()
            let reader = new StreamReader(stream)
            let! html = reader.AsyncReadToEnd()
            return html
          } |> ofAsync
```

But the code can not get compiled, I got the error message:
Error 1 The field, constructor or member 'AsyncReadToEnd' is not defined
So the error was on this line:

```
let! html = reader.AsyncReadToEnd()
```

I guess there could be some changes for the past one year in RX or F#.
For my current environment, what is the correct way to re-write the above code?
Thanks and happy new year to you all!
John

Comment: possible duplicate of [F# AsyncWaitOne and AsyncReadToEnd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535182/f-asyncwaitone-and-asyncreadtoend)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AsyncReadToEnd()` extension method of `StreamReader` is part of [FSharpPowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/) now. Install FSharpPowerPack from [this](https://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/releases) link, if not yet, then add reference to `FSharp.PowerPack` to your project. This should make `AsyncReadToEnd()`method accessible from the rest of your code.

Comment: Hi, Gene Belitski:  Thank you very much!  It works now!  Thanks and happy new year to you!

Comment: `AsyncReadToEnd` extension method has disappeared from latest PowerPack releases. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23293552/1480391

Answer (score 2):

### Use the dedicated AsyncStreamReader type

`AsyncReadToEnd()` extension method does not exists anymore in the [FSharp.PowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/).
It has been replaced with the **`AsyncStreamReader`** dedicated type that contains proper asynchronous implementation of stream reading (like `ReadToEnd`, `ReadLine`, etc.)

It can be used like that:

```
async { 
  use asyncReader = new AsyncStreamReader(stream)
  return! asyncReader.ReadToEnd() }
```

Note: Once you have installed [FSharp.PowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/), the `AsyncStreamReader` type will be 'injected' in the `Microsoft.FSharp.Control` namespace

---

Other related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7925440/1480391